# Como obter nome de usuário do Windows

Tags: asp.net

Estou tentando exibir o nome de funcionários da empresa em um portal intranet. Para usar como saudação, por exemplo, Olá "Fulano".

A forma que cheguei mais próxima disso foi através do asp usando o código abaixo:

```
<%= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>
```

Porém obtém apenas o domínio e o username dessa forma: **Dominio\873059** que é o RE do funcionário, porém quero que obtenha o nome que aparece no menu iniciar por exemplo "Fulano da Silva".

Comment: A sua aplicação usa autenticação do Windows, certo? É uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC ou ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: Usa, a aplicação é ASP.NET

Comment: Isso eu sei. Ela é MVC ou WebForms?

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms